# Problems Updating Flash Player in Opera

Tags: opera

i just cannot update flash player in opera, i'm a new Ubuntu user and i'm not that good with computers anyway so i could really use some help here. Could you please tell me how to do it step by step, as  if you were talking to a rock? I was having trouble even in getting root privileges, so when you get there, please explain it too.

Thanks in advance! (i just can't get to like mozilla)

Comment: Have you tried terminal command: sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree or read this helpful article(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser)

Comment: I already tried the command but i still have the problem.

Comment: And have you tried to compile ffmpeg: http://ruario.ghost.io/2014/12/19/adding-h-264-video-support-to-opera-for-linux/

Comment: what is your current version of flash? are you sure it isn't updated?

Comment: i have no idea how to compile ffmpeg. Anyway i've taken  look at the site you posted, i tried installing chrome as well but it didn't help

Comment: i already upgraded through the command sudo apt-get upgrade but it only works for mozilla, not for opera.

Comment: @ZviadGabroshvili - thats probably for HTML5 video, not flash (which can be used as a alternative to many flash things now though - e.g. https://youtube.com/html5)

Comment: @Fr3 - did you run the command `sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`? (if it didn't work please [edit] in any errors). To get root privileges you need to use the `sudo` command before any commands you want done as root. Also, how did you install opera? If you didn't use a deb package it may not try and access the system's plugins.

Comment: Is flash working now? Why do you think it needs updating? What is the problem with your current flash?

Comment: yes, i installed pepperflashplugin successfully, but it doesn't help. When i'm using opera i can see youtube videos but i can't see anything else on any streaming site like nowvideo, allmyvids etc. (i can watch them fine when using mozilla though). To be honest i do not remember whether i used the terminal, mozilla or the software center.

Comment: This is what i found time ago: http://www.opera.com/docs/linux/plugins/install/#flash unfortunately i do not understand the passages, if you could explain them, i'd be grateful!

Comment: And btw, when i look at Opera's plugins, flash doesn't show up.

Comment: [Here is one proper solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/856329/how-to-install-newest-flash-player-in-opera-and-chromium) for Opera, simple and works.